# Verificar se múltiplas inserções foram concluídas com sucesso em laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Bom dia programadores, tenho uma aplicação que tem um laudo com varias inserções, preciso saber se todas foram executadas com sucesso, estou usando a biblioteca DB:

```
DB::insert('insert into laudo_exemplo(numero, pergunta, procedimento, fk_laudo)
                values (?,?,?,?)',
                [$num_2_11_1, $pergunta_2_11_1, $procesimento2_11_1 , $lastid]
            );
```

Alguém sabe um método para verificar se uma inserção assim foi executada com sucesso?

Answer (score 0):

Cara, é bem simples, para saber quando um código foi compilado com sucesso, jogue ele dentro de um IF. Exemplo.

```
$sql = DB::insert('insert into laudo_exemplo(numero, pergunta, procedimento, fk_laudo) values (?,?,?,?)',[$num_2_11_1, $pergunta_2_11_1, $procesimento2_11_1 , $lastid]);

if($sql)
    return 'Sucesso';

return 'Erro';
```

Comment: É isso mesmo simples assim, não pensei nisso rsrsrs muito obrigado pela ajuda